# Inno Setup PageDescriptionLabel overlapping each other

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I recently made the switch to Inno Setup and it's fantastic!
I was pretty much able to get most of the things to work except I'm having a trouble on something.

Basically, I'm trying to create my own header design and I was trying to make Page Title/Page Description transparent. However they are overlapping each other on page change.
(Please refer to the picture).

[image: http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/6180/88647320.png]

Code:

```
procedure InheritBoundsRect(ASource, ATarget: TControl);
begin
  ATarget.Left := ASource.Left;
  ATarget.Top := ASource.Top;
  ATarget.Width := ASource.Width;
  ATarget.Height := ASource.Height;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  TD: TLabel;
begin
    TD := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
    TD.Parent := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Parent;
    TD.Caption := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;
    TD.WordWrap := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.WordWrap;
    TD.Transparent := True;
    InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel, TD);
    TD.AutoSize := True;
end;
```

Also, I'm not even sure if this is the best way of doing this so if anyone have any suggestion, I'de love to hear them.

Comment: I believe I know the problem, I'm creating a new "TLabel" everytime form is changed so of course a new one will be created on top of the other one; However, I'm still not too sure on how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've correctly pointed out, you're creating your label many times. To be more specific, every time the new page is shown (every time the next or back buttons are pressed). You need to create the label only once, ideally in the wizard form initialization event, like the [`InitializeWizard`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#InitializeWizard). Except that, you then need to change the label's caption every time the page changes. As best for this you need to use that [`CurPageChanged`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#CurPageChanged) event. So, to make transparent page description label (what I missed) you can use script like follows:

```
[Code]
var
  DescLabel: TLabel;

procedure InheritBoundsRect(ASource, ATarget: TControl);
begin
  ATarget.Left := ASource.Left;
  ATarget.Top := ASource.Top;
  ATarget.Width := ASource.Width;
  ATarget.Height := ASource.Height;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  DescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  DescLabel.Parent := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Parent;  
  DescLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.WordWrap;
  DescLabel.AutoSize := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.AutoSize;
  DescLabel.Transparent := True;
  InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel, DescLabel);

  WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Visible := False;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  DescLabel.Caption := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you TLama! I became a very big fan of you today lol.
All the questions I had today, It was mostly answered by you on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry TLama, I've actually tried this method before and the problem was it didn't change every time the page changed. It starts off with TD being "*", and TD stays that way. That's why I moved to  CurPageChanged. So basically, It still does not fully work. 

Is there a way we can define TD globally and just change the value on page change ? or maybe another way ?

Comment: Thank you! It's working perfect now. Also, for some reason having "WordWrap" enabled made label box width smaller and smaller each page change. You could fix that by removing "DescLabel.WordWrap".

Comment: That will be due to autosizing I bet. The original `PageDescriptionLabel` has it set to False whilst the label you create has it by default True. I'll update this...